# Access to nested object via variable index

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Ajax request the response data is an object like this:

[image]

how is possible to access `value`.

note: `idVariable` is a variable.

`data.test1.idVariable.test2.value`

Above code result is: `undefined`.

Comment: `data.test1[idVariable].test2.value`

Comment: Yep, Correct. Thank you haim770.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a variable to name a key in a javascript object you are supposed to use bracket notation. E.g:

```
var idVariable = 8;
var value = data.test1[idVariable].test2.value;
```

Otherwise, you are accessing a key names `idVariable`, instead of `8`

Comment: Already answered and acknowledged as so in comment. Also posted a duplicate link.